# Why is doxygen truncating a parameterized macro function attribute?

Tags: doxygen

Given the following macro definition:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#define WL_PRINTF(x, y) __attribute__((__format__(__printf__, x, y)))
#else
#define WL_PRINTF(x, y)
#endif
```

And given the following use, as a gcc function attribute:

```
typedef void (*wl_log_func_t)(const char *, va_list) WL_PRINTF(1, 0);
```

Doxygen seems to be truncating part of the function attribute, appearing like this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Doxygen also truncates it similarly in other cases where I use the macro function attribute, so the problem seems consistent (it's not about this being a (`typedef`). It documents the macro itself just fine.

My .doxygen config is:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "Wayland"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.12.90
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../../doc/doxygen
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
TAB_SIZE               = 8
QUIET                  = YES
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
MAN_LINKS              = YES
PREDEFINED             = WL_EXPORT=
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
ALIASES                += comment{1}="/* \1 *<!-- -->/"
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
GENERATE_HTML          = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
```

Is there some neat way to trick Doxygen into not truncating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a constraint (pronounced 'bug') in doxygen that causes it to truncate. The alternative is to remove the generation of the function attribute entirely, by adding the macro to the `PREDEFINED` config.